# How do I read the simpleXML object in php?

Tags: php

```
 <?php[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  $try = simplexml_load_file("https://www.theguardian.com/football/series/footballweekly/podcast.xml") ;
  echo "<pre>" ;
  print_r($try) ;
  echo "</pre>" ;
```

Then I try to `echo $try->language` or `$try->item[0]->titel`. Nothing shows, so how can I access this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing out one level of XML:

```
$try->channel->language
$try->channel->item[0]->title
```